# Ionic / Angular HttpClient getting no type data : error Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

In a Ionic project I try to get data from an API by using HttpClient but Angular raise me the **Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.** error.
There is the code of Component and provider method called by component.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';


export class CreerDiscussionPage {
  discussion: Discussion;

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController, 
    public navParams: NavParams,
    public rfcAPI: RfcApiProvider,
    public discussionProvider: DiscussionProvider
    ) {
    this.rfcAPI = rfcAPI;
    this.discussionProvider = discussionProvider;
    this.discussion = new Discussion();
  }

  getDiscussion() {
    this.rfcAPI.getDiscussion()
    .then(data => {
      // Error raised in this place : Property 'name' does not exist on type '{}'.
      console.log(data.name);
    });
  }

}

// Method in the rfcApi provider

import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

.....

  getDiscussion() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/conversation/9a19d9e944e4b105d360614572b715434a365e724beddb83a4f1464a1ea79d29')
      .subscribe(data => {
        resolve(data);
      }, err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
    });

  }
```

Do you know a way to define type of **data** variable returned by HttpClient ? Or other way to solve my issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.then((data: any) => {
      console.log(data.name);
    });
```

Does it maybe work like this?

Also i think you can do this in your service

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/conversation/9a19d9e944e4b105d360614572b715434a365e724beddb83a4f1464a1ea79d29').toPromise()
```